# Change output file when packaging a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, build, package

When I package my extension folder it outputs with the same name and in the same directory

In the terminal:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --pack-extension=./extension
```

My project folder:

```
root/
  extension/
    manifest.json
    ...
  extension.crx
  extension.pem
```

How can I change the name of the `.crx` and `.pem` files and also their destination?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in option in Chrome to change the name or destination. You can either add a command to your build process to move the generated files or use the CRX building scripts published [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx) to directly build the files as you please. The one in [Ruby](https://github.com/Constellation/crxmake) already has the options you need. The bash one would require some modification.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I'm using Python Fabric for building, I'll just play around with it to come up with something.